# Only show specific links via css or javascript/jquery on a widget that renders after the page has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to figure out a solution for a problem I am having on a website but I'm not very good with jquery/javascript.

The page we have renders some javascript after the page has loaded and renders a bunch of html/css on the page, the part we are interested looks like the following:

```
<div class="profile-list">
<a class="profile-profile" href="https://website.com/?profile=joe_blogs_337#show_more">Add loads of html</a>
<a class="profile-profile" href="https://website.com/?profile=sam_smith_292#show_more">Add loads of html</a>
<a class="profile-profile" href="https://website.com/?profile=john_doe_31#show_more">Add loads of html</a>
<a class="profile-profile" href="https://website.com/?profile=stack_overflow_17#show_more">Add loads of html</a>
</div>
```

I am wanting to only show certain profiles, if there any any profiles that do not match then we don't care about them.

I have tried doing it with CSS for example, I can hide individually via:

```
a.profile-profile[href$='?profile=stack_overflow_17#show_more'] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

I can hide all except one via:

```
a.profile-profile:not([href$='?profile=stack_overflow_17#show_more']) {
    display: none !important;
}
```

**However**, If I try and hide all except **two** they all show hidden...

```
a.profile-profile:not([href$='?profile=stack_overflow_17#show_more']), a.profile-profile:not([href$='?profile=john_doe_31#show_more']) {
    display: none !important;
}
```

I'm assuming I can't do this via CSS, therefore I am looking for a fast javascript solution...

Is there a way I can detect when the external js fires so it modifies the rendered HTML as fast as possible?

I'd **rather not** hide all of the links via:

```
.main_content .profile-list .profile-profile{
    display: none;
}
```

To then use

```
$("a[href$=?profile=stack_overflow_17#show_more]").show();
$("a[href$=?profile=john_doe_31#show_more]").show();
```

Any help with the jQuery/Javascript would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you want to filter more `href`s.. You can create an `array` of expected `href`s then use `.filter()` with `.indexOf()` to `hide/show` them

<sup>For exact strings</sup>

```js
var a_Links = [
  "?profile=stack_overflow_17#show_more",
  "?profile=john_doe_31#show_more"
  // add more expected href's .....
];
$('a').filter(function(){
  return a_Links.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) > -1
}).hide();  // to show use `.show()`
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a class="profile-profile" href="just">A Link</a>
<a class="profile-profile" href="?profile=stack_overflow_17#show_more">Another Link</a>
<a class="profile-profile" href="?profile=john_doe_31#show_more">Another 2 Link</a>
```

<sup>**The opposite** And specifically the links inside `.profile-list` element And contains function to find any of strings in the array `indexOf` any of href</sup>

```js
var a_Links = [
  "?profile=stack_overflow_17#show_more",
  "?profile=john_doe_31#show_more"
  // add more expected href's .....
];
$('.profile-list a.profile-profile').filter(function(){
  return contains(a_Links , $(this).attr('href').trim().toLowerCase()) !== 1;
}).hide();  // to show use `.show()`


function contains(a , href) {
  var founded = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      if(founded == 1){break;}
      founded = (href.indexOf(a[i]) > -1) ? 1 : 0;
  }
  return founded;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="profile-list">
  <a class="profile-profile" href="just">A Link</a>
  <a class="profile-profile" href="link?profile=stack_overflow_17#show_more">Another Link</a>
  <a class="profile-profile" href="link?profile=john_doe_31#show_more">Another 2 Link</a>
</div>


<div class="another-profile-list">
  <a class="profile-profile" href="just">A Link</a>
  <a class="profile-profile" href="?profile=stack_overflow_17#show_more">Another Link</a>
  <a class="profile-profile" href="?profile=john_doe_31#show_more">Another 2 Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: **1.** Your code is hiding specific links, I'm wanting to create something opposite that where it has a list of expect links that it wants to keep visible but then it hides the links that don't exist in the matched links.
**2.** I'm using partial links, not full links because it can be on many different URLs
**3.** I can't seem to modify that so it only affects child links of `profile-list` with the class of `profile-profile`.

Comment: @Ryflex see Updated answer

Comment: Ahh, yeah I was doing it the wrong way around `a .profile-list` and was trying `==` not `===`. As for my point 2, for some reason it doesn't allow a portion of the link... the actual links are `https://website.com/?profile=stack_overflow_17#show_more` but I am only interested in filtering by `?profile=stack_overflow_17#show_more` I guess a cleaner way would be for me to be able to just list their profile ID's which would be: `17` for one of them, just it would need to automatically add a `_` before and `#show_more` after to make sure it's looking for the actual ID.

Comment: @Ryflex also take in consider the lowercase and the uppercase for that you can use lowercase inside the array then use `$(this).attr('href').trim().toLowerCase()`

Comment: @Ryflex also take in consider the lowercase and the uppercase for that you can use lowercase inside the array then use `$(this).attr('href').trim().toLowerCase()`

Comment: Yeah, I had already tried those but they don't make any difference. See https://jsfiddle.net/h4e3scb2/ it doesn't work even if you add that.

Comment: @Ryflex Sorry for delay on reply but I've a really bad connection .. see my opposite updated answer .. choose between `== 1` and `!== 1` and between `show()` and `hide()`

Comment: that's a very nice bit of code, I made a few tweaks to it and it's perfect. Your "contains" function is super helpful!

Comment: I'm glad its finally works for you  .. And to be honest I guess there is another simple idea than this but yesterday I'd sticked with this one ..anyways If I found another simple way I'll let you know :-) .. Have a great day :-) @Ryflex

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let removeProfiles = [
'?profile=stack_overflow_17#show_more',
'?profile=john_doe_31#show_more',
];

$('a.profile-profile').hide();

removeProfiles.forEach(profile=>{

 $('a.profile-profile[href$="'+profile+'"]').show()

})
```

Comment: That appears to work the opposite to what I am trying to acheive, I want to "keep" the listed profiles, I want to hide the ones that aren't listed! Plus it throws "undefined" at the end of when its ran.

Comment: make sure to change removeProfiles array's values, although when I run it in console JS always returns undefined.

Comment: i have made some changes, run that JS code without jsfiddle